# WordPress & BuddyPress Issue storing special and latin characters to the databse & Display issue

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, collation, buddypress

I have one site and on this site, I am using BuddyPress plugin as well. But Now I am facing the issue related to special and the latin character storing into the database as well as displaying Wrongly on the front end.

For Example:

1) ö is displaying like u006f

2) Jörg is displaying like Ju00f6rg

I have also checked my Config file and there is setup like below:

define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8’);

define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ‘utf8_unicode_ci’);

If I remove above two configurations from the config file then I am facing the issue of saving all the data into the database.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The source data is at fault, not the products mentioned here.  (OK, maybe BuddyPress goofed.)

Where did the data come from?  Some products use the "Unicode" `\u00f6` format, and the `\` was lost somewhere else.

Let's distinguish two similar terms:

- `ö` is a `latin` character.
- `ö` is *encoded* in `latin1` as one byte, hex `F6`, or in `utf8` as two bytes, hex `C3B6`, or in ascii as the six characters `\u00F6`.  The last assumes that the reader understands that convention.  You hit someone that does not.